# Define raster marker symbology for new point (keep simple marker for pre-existing points)

Tags: pyqgis, symbology

I want to display a raster marker for a point created by the user, while keeping the existing, processed points with a simple marker symbology.

I can change the size or color of the symbology for the new point with `QgsRuleBasedRenderer` (new point comes with a specific value), but trying to associate a raster marker either converts all the existing points in the layer to raster markers, or isn't displayed at all.

This is part of the pyQGIS function after creating the new point by clicking on the map:

```
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    
    renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
    root = renderer.rootRule()

    symbolStart = root.children()[0].clone()
    symbolStart.setFilterExpression("\"Number\" = '-1'")
    symbolStart.symbol().setSize(5) # this works well, only the new point is resized

    root.appendChild(symbolStart)
    layer.setRenderer(renderer)
   
    rstpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'pad.png')
    rstsize = 5 
    rstlayer = QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer(rstpath, rstsize)
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry)
    symbol.appendSymbolLayer(rstlayer)
    renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol) # this line converts all points to raster markers

    layer.setRenderer(renderer)

    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

This is so easy to do with the main QGIS interface, but how to add/associate the `QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer` with the new point?

Comment: I'm trying now with a .qml style file, but it doesn't save the units of the Raster Marker size (it always reverts back to 'map units' instead of 'mm'), nor the 'Symbol levels', meaning that the Simple Marker is always on top of the Raster Marker...

Comment: Editing the .qml file by hand was the only way. The marker option 'size_unit' was not saved correctly (QGIS 3.22 Win10 Pro), changing its value from 'map_unit_scale' to 'MM', and parameter 'pass' to a higher value than the simple marker seems to be enough. Instead of using the pyQGIS renderer, the edited .qml file is loaded (file saved together with the python script)...